# Is it possible to setup a DHCP server only for local virtual machines?

Tags: networking, vmware, dhcp, nat

I have a quick question. I have a bunch of virtual machines (VMWare Workstation) running on an Ubuntu server and have found that VMWare NAT (DHCP) service is unreliable and slow. I have to use NAT instead of bridging because the server is in a data-center that does not have DHCP and I don't have enough static IP's for all the VMs.

Is it possible to setup the host (Ubuntu) to be a DHCP server but only for the local virtual machines?

The server has two network interfaces, so I'd set `eth0` to be a static IP, which connects to the outside world, and `eth1` to listen for DHCP. Now, I am thinking if I don't want DHCP to broadcast I would just not connect a cable to `eth1` and setup the VM's to use bridging on `eth1`. That way DHCP would not broadcast through my network but be listening on that interface.

Would that setup work?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `dnsmasq` - the `man dnsmasq` page says it does DHCP serving with static address assignments.

Comment: Well, @thiesdiggity did `dnsmasq` solve your problem? Did the answer actually WORK?

Comment: poor answer....